# Uniqueness of the splitting field of a polynominal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

I tried to prove a proposition from field theory, dealing with the uniqueness of splitting fields and not sure if it's right. Here's my work:

Let $K$ be a field and  $f \in K[T]$ a polynominal. Let's say that $L$ and $E$ are splitting fields of $f$. We need to show that $ E \cong L$

We know that every polynominal has a splitting field and that if $f$ is monic ( it could be since  $K$ is a field) and $f:=\prod_{\nu=1}^{n}(T-a_{\nu})$, where $a_{1};...;a_{n} \in E$, the splitting field, then $E \cong K[a_{1};...;a_{n}]$ (I'm not going to prove this results here because I've alreday encountered them. Try to prove them if you want)

Induction on $deg(f)$:

$P(1)$: Let $deg(f)=1$. Define $f:=aT+b \in K[T]$. Now, $f=a(T-(-a^{-1}b))$ and hence $K$ is the only splitting field of $f$ and obviously $K \cong K$.

$P(n) \Longrightarrow P(n+1)$: Let $deg(f)=n+1$ and let's assume that for any polynominal of degree $n$, it's splitting fields are isomorphic. Let's define $f:=\sum_{\nu=o}^{n}a_{\nu}T^{\nu}$.
Let $E$ and $L$ be splitting fields of $f$ (again, we assume that $f$ is monic) and define: $f:=\prod_{\nu=1}^{n+1}(T-a_{\nu})=\prod_{\nu=1}^{n+1}(T-c_{\nu})$ with the $a_{\nu}$ terms in $E$ and the $c_{\nu}$ terms in $L$ resp. such that $g:=\prod_{\nu=1}^{n}(T-a_{\nu})=\prod_{\nu=1}^{n}(T-c_{\nu})$.
Now, if we let $E'$ and $L'$ be splitting fields of $g$, since $deg(g)=n$ by the induction hypotesis, $E' \cong L'$. But from the definition of $g$, we deduce that $T-a_{n+1}=T-c_{n+1}$ and therefore $b:=a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}$. From the previous isomorphism, we get that \begin{equation} \begin{split} E'& \cong L' \Leftrightarrow K[a_{1};...;a_{n}] \cong K[c_{1};...;c_{n}] \Longrightarrow E'[b] \cong L'[b] \Leftrightarrow K[a_{1};...;a_{n};b]  &\cong K[c_{1};...;c_{n};b] \end{split}\end{equation} but since $b=a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}$, this holds:
 $E \cong K[a_{1};...;a_{n};a_{n+1}] \cong K[c_{1};...;c_{n};c_{n+1}] \cong L \Leftrightarrow E \cong L$ which is the final result.

Therefore, since $P(1)$ and the implication $P(n) \Longrightarrow P(n+1)$ hold, $P(n),\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}$ holds.

Please answer if I'm right and if I'm not, show me the mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can have $g\not\in K[T]$. Removing one root you lose control on the coefficients.

The uniqueness of the splitting field is stated as Theorem 3.1 in page 236 of Lang's [Algebra](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387953854). There you'll find an exposition better than I could ever do here.

Comment: Thanks. I should have realised it from the fact that there is no other intermediate field that is also a splitting one.

Comment: The best way prove, I think, is to construct the isomorphism as Lang does. It is a nice clean argument but relies on other stuff he proves before.

Comment: But does it still hold that if we took E' and L' just as field extensions, they are still isomorphic?

Comment: It should still work.